# Sending Keypress to Iframe

Tags: javascript

I have a cross domain iframe. My locally run file is calling say website.com and I was to send a keypress from my local file to the iframe website.

I understand that due to cross domain restrictions this is not possible easily through the DOM

Is there anyway to do this with say postMessage or any workaround?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  Your best bet may be to create a Greasemonkey / Tampermonkey script.

Comment: Interesting I shall google what those terms are but can you add anything quickly? Just what are those in general

Comment: Greasemonkey and Tampermonkey let you add your own JavaScript to 3rd party websites.  Greasemonkey is a Firefox add-on.  Tampermonkey is for Google Chrome.